# Method: projects.androidApps.create always return error

Tags: google-apis-explorer

***Note:*** I am posting this question regarding  from this site suggestion
https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support

parent=projects/887503652605

body
{
"name": "name",
"displayName": "d name",
"projectId": "pp",
"packageName": "ds.asdas.sdds",
"appId": "1:222475557139:android:b85702f52a4e128dcaaaaa"
}
Here what is appId and how to get it before adding app in firebase project

{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

Comment: did you found any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try only:
`{ "displayName": "d name","packageName": "ds.asdas.sdds" }`

- projectId is located in API: https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/androidApps/
- appId is given by firebase **(unique)**
- name is given by firebase: `projects/$PROJECT_ID/androidApps/$APP_ID`

Comment: How can I locate `appId`?